# Initialize vuejs app

Tags: vue.js

I'm very new to vuejs world and I'm trying to move my existing application to vuejs.

I use Laravel as a backend framework. I got a lot of entities and settings, and in order to the app to work properly I need to retrieve from server some necessary data like user role etc. So basically I need to:

1. Hide the whole app and show a loader instead
2. Make few ajax requests in order to retrieve data from server
3. Store the data somewhere, so that it's accessible everywhere in vuejs app
4. Hide loader and run the app

The data might be changed though, for example, I have a team and team members. The list of team members used in many places. So if I add a team member the team member list should be updated as well.

So I don't want to have a global javascript variable for storing such data, because any modifications in this variable should affect the data-binding and stuff.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: If I were you, I would build one or two playground projects in Vue before attempting to move an existing application (moving an existing app to another framework can be an exhausting and confusing piece of work if you already know the target framework, let alone if you don't...)

Comment: Oh this is just an experiment, I took existing project just in order to play with vue. Don't like dealing with "todo apps" because they don't arise real questions of how do to real things

Comment: Fair point - just wanted to warn against the rabbit-hole effect of switching an entire app to a new framework - if it's just for learning purposes then, no danger at all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use case seems appropriate to using [Vuex](http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html).

From Vuex documentation:

> Vuex is an application architecture for centralized state management
>   in Vue.js applications. It is inspired by Flux and Redux, but with
>   simplified concepts and an implementation that is designed
>   specifically to take advantage of Vue.js' reactivity system.

In other words, it is specifically designed to handle situations such as:

> The data might be changed though, for example, I have a team and team
>   members. The list of team members used in many places. So if I add a
>   team member the team member list should be updated as well.